# Entering a strategy x days before ex-date

Tags: pine-script

I am playing around with a dividend capture strategy and I'd like to enter a strategy a few days before an ex-date.

I already have all the ex-dates loaded using something like this -

`dividendsUnixTimeStamp = request.security(esdSymbolTemplate + ";DIVIDENDS", "D", time)`

How do I check if the current bar is x days before the next ex-date?

Thanks so much.

Comment: There is no such possibility yet (to look into future bars for ESD data from the Pine script).

Answer (score 2):

From the dark side of the Pine Script power:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, process_orders_on_close = true)

daysLeftToNearestDividend()=>
    exDate = request.security(__dividends_tickerid(syminfo.tickerid), "3M", high, gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
    daysLeft = math.ceil((exDate - time/1000) / (60*60*24))
    daysLeft >= 0 ? daysLeft : na

daysBeforeDivsEnter = input(14, "days before dividend open position")
daysBeforeDivsExit = input(1, "days before dividend close position")
daysLeft = daysLeftToNearestDividend()

gone(daysBefore, daysLeft) =>
    daysBefore == daysLeft or ( daysBefore > daysLeft and daysBefore < daysLeft[1] )

if gone(daysBeforeDivsEnter, daysLeft)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)

if gone(daysBeforeDivsExit, daysLeft)
    strategy.close_all(immediately = true)
```

P.S. Tested on AAPL,D history only. No guarantees that it will work in real time ;)

Comment: Thanks, Andrey!

Works perfectly for AAPL. But doesn't seem to work for stuff like VIG or VYM. Do you know why is that?

Comment: yes. The ex div date is a first day of week )

Comment: the new input added. You can tune it's value for particular symbol

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Just wondering, is there ia way to find the diffence in bars between two dates? This should solve the holiday counting problems cleanly?